# HTML - Position an image in a new line

Tags: html, css, positioning, image

I have a series of paragraphs. Each one ends with a illustration which clarifies the subject being explained in the paragraph.

I want the illustration to be on a new line and not display along with the text and I have found the following solutions, with it's own problems:

Put the illustration in a different <p> than the text related to the illustration.

```
<p>Some text here<p/>
<p><img src="myphoto"/></p>
```

This seems to solve all the problems, but later I needed to enclose some of this paragraphs inside a `<ul>` instead of a `<p>`. The problem being I cannot enclose the `<p>` tag for the illustration inside a `<li>` and does not make sense to put the illustration inside a `<li>`.

```
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <p><img src="myphoto"/></p><!--Incorrect-->
    <li><img src="myphoto"/></li><!--Does not make sense-->
</ul>
```

Put the ilulstration inside the same `<p>` as the text. Then use  `<br/>` tag to move the picture to a new line. I'm not really happy with this workaround, the `<br/>` is doing presentational stuff that should be better in CSS.

```
<p>Some text here<br/><img src="myphoto"/></p>
```

Finally, set the display attribute of the `<img>` as block in the CSS style sheet. I'm not sure if this is a good way and don't know the unrelated consequences it may have.

I don't know if there is a standard way of doing this. I have search for CSS to start my image in a new line but did not find it. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, so this is my new solution. Basically, we just set the IMG element to be a block-level element.

```
img { display:block; }
```

This solution does not introduce any new markup. (You just place the `<img>` element right after the text in the paragraph / list item.)

I believe this to be the most elegant solution, since setting images to be blocks is rather common anyway.

Comment: David's point is he doesn't want a separate bullet for the illustrative image that follows the text - it's not a separate item, it doesn't make sense to have it's own bullet.

Comment: Rudu says exactly what I think, and Sime Vidas agrees with him and concludes his help is not rigth, but I cannot undestand. If I use a <br> tag inside the <li> tag to put the image in a new line I'm avoiding using a different <li> tag for the image and I getting it display in a new line. Is it rigth?

Comment: Your updated solution also seems the better for me. I can't see the need of an outer DIV as JacobM suggests below. There may be the need to add a CLASS attribute to the IMG so not every image gets display in a new line.

Comment: Yes, of course. Setting all images to blocks would be nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your image:

`<BR CLEAR=ALL />` … or

`<BR CLEAR=RIGHT|LEFT />`

basic HTML, no CSS! :)